# AngularJS not able to include markup in IDs?

Tags: angularjs

I have an array of 3 items and want them to be "ng-repeated"

```
<li ng-repeat="item in obj.items id="testobj{{testobj.number}}">
</li>
```

When I look at the page, it appears that the id of the "li" is just "testobj" for all 3 items and not testobj1 testobj2 testobj3 like I was expecting. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ng-repeat` attribute is missing a final ".

The {{ }} binding is probably coming back with no data and so being treated as if it was an empty string. I see no reference to `testobj` (the scope variable) anywhere outside of your binding. Is this defined, or should your id read `id="testobj{{item.number}}"` or something similar?